How to achieve two way data binding in Angular
How can I achieve a pattern in Angular that resembles React's uni-directional data flow and state management? I want to implement two-way data binding where data updates propagate bidirectionally between components, akin to React's approach using props and state. What are the recommended techniques or best practices in Angular to achieve this level of data synchronization?

I am not familiar with React but have you checked the two-way binding docs?

I am assuming you are using the latest version of angular, so I suggest going for signals and the a good one to use for two way data binding is to use model.
Below is a working example using model to create two way data binding between parent and child.
import { Component, model } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="someInput"/>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  someInput = model();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [Child, FormsModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="someInput"/>
    <div>Below is the child:</div>
    <app-child [(someInput)]="someInput"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  someInput = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

You can import Forms Module and then leverage the ngModel attribute to have two way binding in angular.
<input id="username" [(ngModel)]="username" />

username should be a public variable declared in the component. The same variable can be used globally across the component.

If you're trying to match the uni-directional data flow and state management (which is a "reactive" approach), you should check out:

Signals in Angular - Simple way to lazily propagate changes to data within a component. Relatively new feature.
ngrx - Literally "Angular Reactive". For more advanced application state management that sticks heavily to reactive data flow. Interoperates with Angular Signals.
Reactive forms in Angular A uni-directional way . Two-way effect achieved by subscribing to valueChanges observable (on FormControl or FormGroup).

In our (longtime production) Angular application, we use all 3.
